# How to make an Express asynchronous search render with hbs?

Tags: express

I'm making an asynchronous search using an event listener on `keyDown`  and in the template its outputting all of the records from the database, however if I console log the `jobs` object I can see it's only returning the records based on the keyword.

The Issue:
[image]

**Route - search.js (server)**

```
const express = require('express');
const Job = require('../Model/job')
const router = new express.Router();

router.post("/search", async (req, res) => {

  const title = req.body.keyword;

  try {

    const jobs = await Job.find({"title": new RegExp(title)});

    res.status(200).send({jobs: jobs})
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error);
  }
});

module.exports = router
```

**search.js (frontend)**

```
const $keyword = document.querySelector('#keyword');
const $jobs = document.querySelector('#jobs');
const jobsTemplate = document.querySelector('#jobs-template').innerHTML;

$keyword.addEventListener('keydown', (event)=>{

  search('/search', { keyword: $keyword.value }).then(data => {

    const jobs = data.jobs;

    const html = Mustache.render(jobsTemplate, {jobs});
    $jobs.innerHTML = html;
    
    console.log(jobs);

  }).catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error);
  });

});
```

**index.hbs (template)**

```
<div class="card-columns" id="jobs">

<script id="jobs-template" type="text/html">
  {{#each jobs}}
    <a class="card-link" href="/job/{{_id}}">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{title}}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">{{description}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
{{/each}}
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/3.0.1/mustache.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/search.js"></script>
```

**index.js (server)**

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require('path');
require("./Database/mongoose");
const jobRouter = require('./Route/job');
const searchRouter = require('./Route/search');
const hbs = require("hbs");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// define paths for Express config
const publicDirPath = path.join(__dirname, "../public");
const viewsPath = path.join(__dirname, "../templates/views");
const partialsPath = path.join(__dirname, "../templates/partials");

// setup handlebars templating engine and template location
app.set("view engine", "hbs");
app.set("views", viewsPath);
hbs.registerPartials(partialsPath);


app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(express.json());
app.use(jobRouter);
app.use(searchRouter);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server is up on ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `jobsTemplate` variable does not contain your original template.  Instead, it contains already rendered HTML (that shows all the records).  So, when you try to render new data with:

```
const html = Mustache.render(jobsTemplate, {jobs});
```

`jobsTemplate` isn't actually a template.  It's already-rendered HTML.  So handlebars finds no template directives and just returns the original content unchanged.  You then dutifully insert that unchanged content into your page and the search query results never show.

To use client-side rendering, you have to make sure that the client has access to the original, unmodified handlebars template.  This would typically involve including the template in your HTML page in a way that it is not rendered when delivering it to the client so the client can then get the original template text.  Then, when you do use that template and insert new content in the page, make sure you've stored the original template data so you can use it again as needed.

Comment: So I modified it to not do server-side rendering, however the template is still not rendering the data. Perhaps I'm just being thick.

Comment: @KerrialBeckettNewham - Do a View Source on your page in the browser and see if the template is there with the right ID value in your page.  Then do the `console.log(jobsTemplate)` where you had it before (as I suggested in comments) and see if you have the right template?

Comment: The template is there, but it's empty and the console log doesn't output anything.

Comment: you can see the code here https://github.com/Kerrialn/express-asynchronous-search-example